# Growth Rate of Number of Divisors of Highly Composite Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $H(k)$ be the $k^{th}$ highly composite number (HCN).

1. What is an asymptotic estimate for the size of $H(k)$ in terms of $k.$
2. What is an asymptotic estimate for the size of $d(H(k))$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Even though there are a lot of related questions and answers on Math Stackexchange, I haven't been able to find clear answers to these questions. I asked the same question with no comments or responses over 10 days in Math Stackexchange.

In relation to question 1, a page at Bielefeld university [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.html) has numerical evidence suggesting
$$
\ln H(k) \sim \ln 2 (\ln k)^{4/5}.
$$
Has such a result been proved?

With regard to question 2, I presume the main question is whether $d(H(k))$ actually grows as fast as that implied by the well known
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \frac{\log d(n)}{\frac{ \log n}{\log \log n}}=\log 2.
$$

Comment: The answer to your question 1 is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number#Asymptotic_growth_and_density, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Highly composite numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002182 with many comments/formulas/links/references. Might be a good place to start.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz, what I am asking is the growth in the size of the HCNs, not the growth in the cardinality of the set of HCNs. Specifically whether the numerical evidence I mention in the Uni Bielefeld site been proved?

Comment: Hey do you mean to have a k^{4/5} on the right-hand side? That’s consistent with both Wikipedia and the page you’ve linked. Note that Wikipedia gives you bounds of e^{k^{1/1.7... + o(1)}} < H(k) < e^{k^{1/1.13... + o(1)}} (unless I’ve made a dumb mistake!).

Comment: @alpoge, thanks, will have another look at wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alpoge, @NoahStephens-Davidowitz, @GerryMyerson for their help, as is obvious to everyone I am not an expert in this.

I can now see how come we have
$$
\exp\left\{k(1/1.71\cdots+o(1))\right\} < H(k) < \exp\left\{k(1/1.13862\cdots+o(1))\right\},
$$
which answers Question 1.

As for Question 2, I made computations with the tables provided by Achim Flammenkamp [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.txt), which seem to suggest that $d(H(k))$ eventually grows faster than $(\ln H(k))^a,$ for small values of $a$ (tested up to $a=7$).

So, my question on whether $d(H(k))$ achieves the growth rate given by
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \frac{\log d(n)}{\frac{ \log n}{\log \log n}}=\log 2,
$$
which dominates any fixed power of $\log n$ still stands, in my mind. Perhaps it is "obvious" that HCN's are the numbers which have to hit this $\lim \sup$ upper boundary, but not to me.